# Unvoluntarily page break [SOLVED]

Tags: page-breaking

my TeX editor makes a page break on when I try to make some space (\vspace) between my tabulars and images, and doesn't when I omit the vspace, but then the page is loaded.

Here's my code :

```
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{figure}

    %Tableau 1.2
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{2.7cm}|C{5cm}|C{3.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|}
    \hline  & $\beta$ &  $D$ &  $a=\dfrac{\beta_{2}}{\beta_{1}}$  \\
    \hline  Fonte (1) & $1.3 \times 10^{4} \cdot \joule \cdot \kelvin^{-1}\cdot \meter^{-2} \cdot \second^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ & $1.4 \times 10^{-5} \cdot \meter^{2}\cdot \second^{-1} $ & \multirow{2}*{$1.76$} \\
    \cline{1-3}  Aluminium (2) & $2.3 \times 10^{4} \cdot \joule \cdot \kelvin^{-1} \cdot \meter^{-2} \cdot \second^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ & $ 10^{-4}\cdot \meter^{2} \cdot \second^{-1} $ & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Grandeurs thermiques caractéristiques et rapport des effusivités}

    \\
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    %Tableau 2
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
    \hline $t $ & $0s$ & $20 s$ &  $60 s$ &  $120 s$ & $180 s$ & $240 s$  \\
    \hline $T_{1} (°C)$ & $22.0$ & $27.4$ & $32.5$ & $38.8$ & $49.9$ & $59.2$ \\
    \hline $T_{2} (°C)$ & $21.2$ & $30.1$ & $45.2$ & $49.3$ & $68.0$ & $75.0$ \\
    \hline $T_{3} (°C)$ & $20.5$ & $27.0$ & $34.6$ & $39.1$ & $50.5$ & $55.5$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Récapitulatif des résultats de l'expérience}

    \\
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ct1.png}
         \caption{Dispositif au cours de                        l'expérience}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{3.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ct2.png}
         \caption{Pièce en Fonte (1) après l'expérience}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
```

This is the result I get : [image: enter]

My preamble :

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{color}
    \def\idt{\hspace{\parindent}}
    \def\vt{\vrule height 0mm depth 2mm width 0mm}
    \def\vtt{\vrule height 0mm depth 3mm width 0mm}
    \def\vttt{\vrule height 0mm depth 13mm width 0mm}
    \def\vtr#1{\vrule height 0mm depth #1mm width 0mm}
    \def\wtr#1#2{\vrule height #2mm depth #1mm width 0mm}

    \usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}         
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt} % Marge gauche sur pages impaires
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{9pt} % Marge gauche sur pages paires
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{54pt} % Largeur de note dans la marge
    \setlength{\textwidth}{481pt} % Largeur de la zone de texte (17cm)
    \setlength{\voffset}{-18pt} % Bon pour DOS
    \setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt} % Séparation de la marge
    \setlength{\topmargin}{0pt} % Pas de marge en haut
    \setlength{\headheight}{13pt} % Haut de page
    \setlength{\headsep}{10pt} % Entre le haut de page et le texte
    \setlength{\footskip}{27pt} % Bas de page + séparation
    \setlength{\textheight}{708pt} % Hauteur de la zone de texte (25cm)
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %pour avoir les accents 
    \usepackage[french]{babel}%pour avoir une syntaxe en français
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%pour une belle mise en page des accents
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{stmaryrd} 

    %Tableaux
    \usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
    \setcellgapes{1pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
```

Thanks in avance !

Comment: `figure` is a floating environment, so putting it inside `center` does not make sense.  Does any of the discussion under http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15925 help?

Comment: remove the `\\ ` before the vspace that's completely wrong (don't you get a no line here to end error??) remove the center from outside the figure, other than that it is impossible to say unless you make a complete example that people can test.

Comment: You should use a separate `figure`, or `table`, environment for each figure, or table.

Comment: this is not related but usefull http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf

Comment: Thank you everybody, everything helped. Have a good day ! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been solved mysteriously.